# Convert ASCII to UTF8 database

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to convert an SQL_ASCII database into UTF8.
pg-dump doesn't seem to work at all. No error, no explanation.
So, I'm using my plan B.

All my tables are re-created on the new UTF8 database.
However, now it's impossible to use export-import since my data is in ASCII.

I tried the convert function.

```
select convert("myField", 'SQL_ASCII', 'UTF8') from "myTable" 

--return function convert(character varying, unknown, unknown) doesn't exist
```

I tried the most simple way to convert for fun

```
select convert('test', 'SQL_ASCII', 'UTF8')
return '[binary data]'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This is going to need more information 1) Postgres version you dumped from? 2) The version pg_dump you used to do the dump? 3) Postgres version you restored to? 4) How did you do the restore? 5) Text of full commands used to do the preceding.  FYI, `SQL_ASCII` is not an actual encoding. See here [Character sets](https://github.com/plv8/plv8/blob/r3.1alpha/docs/BUILDING.md) bottom of 23.3.1. Supported Character Sets section.

Comment: I should have put in previous comment that the information needs to be added to your question.

Comment: 1) Postgres version is 13.3

Comment: 2) I did not knew there was a version of pg_dump, i'll look for it but the way I did it was : pg_dump -U uniiverse --encoding utf8 MyDB -f >C:\temp\db.sql;

Comment: 3) Same server, different database.   4) Not there yet   5) You have the full command line of the dump in 2

Comment: Please add this information to your question. Also this `-f >C:\temp\db.sql` is not going to work. Then there is this `C:\temp\db.sql;` which would seem to imply you where doing the dump inside a client as a query. That won't work either, `pg_dump` is a client program that needs to be run at the command line. See here [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) Examples section at bottom.